# ARIMA Fitting: CSS vs CSS log likelihood

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, arima

Can someone explain to me: in estimating the parameters for an ARIMA model, what is the advantage of optimizing the [CSS log likelihood](http://www.nuffield.ox.ac.uk/economics/papers/1997/w6/ma.pdf)(pg 2), versus optimizing [CSS](http://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/93589.pdf) (pg 3)? Are there any advantages/disadvantages to either? I realize the standard way of optimizing ARIMA models is using MLE with Kalman filters, but ran into this question about CSS as I read up on alternate estimation techniques.

Comment: CSS is the fastest and the least accurate, MLE is the slowest but the most accurate; CSS-MLE is a hybrid (medium fast, medium accurate).

Comment: MLE is your best choice when you have low sample size. CSS is faster when you have lots of data